# Can't import a copy as fetch to postman

Tags: javascript, java, postman, google-chrome-devtools

just want to  copy a request in developers tools>network as a fetch
and create  a postman request but I do everything right but fails to send.

```
fetch("https://myurl/dwr/call/plaincall/AjaxManager.getServerTime.dwr", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "text/plain",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
  },
  "referrer": "https://myurl/mmtpOrder.do?0.48252636885821754",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "callCount=1\nnextReverseAjaxIndex=0\nc0-scriptName=AjaxManager\nc0-methodName=getServerTime\nc0-id=0\nbatchId=0\ninstanceId=1\npage=%2FmmtpOrder.do%3F0.48252636885821754\nscriptSessionId=wabwhC8DKY9tH4o9ZUqUVRjyYDpwxbcCsDn/ze32tDn-CLLquBS6a\n",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

I should say this is shown as a response in chrome>Developers tool>network

```
throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
//#DWR-INSERT
//#DWR-REPLY
//#DWR-START#
(function(){
if(!window.dwr)return;
var dwr=window.dwr._[1];`enter code here
dwr.engine.remote.handleCallback("0","0",1622904081778);
})();
//#DWR-END#
dwr.engine.remote.handleCallback("0","0",1622904081778);
})();
//#DWR-END#`enter code here`
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the root cause may be. But you can try to change "referrer" to "referer" and see if it works. Some frameworks do use the latter according to my knowledge.